# Google AdMob Unity Interstitial display/close logic

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I'm just trying to figure out how to display Interstitial ad in my Unity game and I'm looking for suggestions/examples of how to detect that it was closed so I can continue the game. The logic is this: user starts the new game, the Unity checks if this user has seen the ad in the last X minutes and if not, it displays the ad. But what am I supposed to do next? How do I know if they closed the ad or it ran out of time (ad ended) so I can continue? I'm I supposed to use `OnAdFullScreenContentClosed` or `OnAdImpressionRecorded` from here: https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/interstitial? I don't see a simple `OnAdClosed` here.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks.